# apply Iris Dataset target names to the confusion matrix

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

good evening, i   have done KNN  classifier method for iris dataset, i can show all code, but i think it is not important to post full code, only one fragment which i did not understand  is how to   assign iris target names to the confusion matrix? here is confusion matrix

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction))
```

which returns  matrix

```
[[13  0  0]
 [ 0 15  1]
 [ 0  0  9]]
```

i have searched in internet [Confussion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

and i know that there is  additional parameter labels, so i have tried

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
class_names =iris_dataset["target_names"]
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction,labels=class_names))
```

but i got following error :

```
ValueError: At least one label specified must be in y_true
```

please help me how to fix it?

Comment: if your time is  so valuable and  you consider that  time is money, then  it is not obligatory to  answer someone, i  have some difficulties with  R language  and trying to help her, when i post qustion nobody is answering me, so i  lost hope of this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went there a few months ago, here is a piece of code, try to adapt it to your needs;)
original is the original dataset iris dataset
and prediction is the prediction made on the classification

I hope this will help you !

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix

myarray = np.asarray(original)
matrix = confusion_matrix((myarray),(predictions+1))

class_names = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']

fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=matrix,
                                show_absolute=True,
                                show_normed=False,
                                colorbar=True,
                                class_names=class_names)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you  , the same i have tried  , thanks for helping me , it is already solved, but  for shake of personal respect, i will upvote and accept

Comment: Hey Thony, can you update your answer using ConfusionMatrixDisplay because plot_confusion_matrix is now deprecated as of 29-June-2023.